# Does SAP support XBRL as standard?

Tags: sap-erp, xbrl

Does SAP support XBRL as standard? If so, from which version? Are certain SAP components required for XBRL?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.
Note 1278989 - SAP strategy for creating XBRL documents:

> In addition to the solution delivered
>   with ERP 6.0 Enhancement Package 3,
>   SAP provides a new solution for
>   creating XBRL documents since February
>   2009.
>
> Solution:
>
> Since February 2009, SAP provides a
>   new XBRL solution for SAP Business
>   Suite with the following features:
>
> ```
> * Generation of XBRL instance documents from Microsoft Excel files,
> ```
>
> which can be created using SAP
>   NetWeaver BEx Analyzer, among others.
>
> ```
> * Integrated validation of XBRL instance documents
>
> * Editing of XBRL instance documents
>
> * Enhancement of XBRL taxonomies
> ```
>
> The new solution is described at
>   http://www.sap.com/solutions/sapbusinessobjects/large/enterprise-performance-management/xbrl-publishing/index.epx
>
> Just as with the previous solution in
>   SAP ERP 6.0 Enhancement Package 3, you
>   can use this to evaluate all data
>   which can be accessed using SAP NW BI,
>   that is, in particular also data from
>   SEM-BCS.
>
> If you have any questions about the
>   cost of the new solution, contact your
>   account manager.
>
> The previous XBRL function in SAP ERP
>   6.0 is still available but is not being further developed. Therefore, we
>   recommend that you use the new
>   solution for all XBRL reporting
>   requirements.
>
> The previous XBRL function is
>   maintained according to the SAP
>   maintenance strategy for SAP ERP. This
>   is published on SAP Service
>   Marketplace at
>   http://service.sap.com/releasestrategy.